# Visual Studio 2012 and Blend which version(s)?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, blend

I'm sorry if these are really noob questions but I am new to the Visual Studio C# world and confused about what I will and will not be able to do with the Express editions and how they differ from the Professional Edition.

I installed Visual Studio Express for Desktops a couple of weeks ago.
I have seen MVVM tutorials using Blend (Expression Blend?) which looks a great tool for creating modern looking apps that will scale on different devices.
However, I can't find Blend in my current install - it appears to only come with the Express for Windows 8 product.

So I have a couple of questions, bearing in mind I want to eventually purchase the Professional Edition:

1. Can the different versions of Express be installed at the same time ?
2. Can you install Blend separately ?
3. Is Blend only suitable for Windows 8 apps or can it be used for older desktop WPF ? (I read something about Update 2 allowing this ?)
4. Is the Express for Windows 8 product only suitable for windows 8 apps or could they be compiled to run on Vista and up ?
5. Will the Professional version give me:
   Blend ?
   The ability to maintain older VS2010 WPF solutions ?
   The ability to style desktop apps which will run on Vista+ (XP even?) ?
   The ability to create WinRT and Windows 8+ apps ?
6. Do you have to install and run VS2012 on Windows 8 if you are targeting Windows 8 ?

I'm a single developer and want to be able to do everything and make it look cool on all Microsoft OS - what do I need ? (That's a rhetorical question btw)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, cou can install different Versions of Visual Studio Express

   - I have installed

     - VS 2012 Express for Windows Phone
     - VS 2012 Express for Windows 8
     - VS 2012 Express for Windows Desktop
     - VS 2012 Ultimate (which can all this things at once)
2. Yes you can install blend seperatly, but I dont know if theres a free Version
3. You can use Blend for WPF Application as well
4. Express for Windows 8 is only for Windows 8 Apps
5. Yes, you can also build WinRT Projects (if you have installed the sdk)
6. Yes, you only can develop Windows 8 (WinRT Apps) or Windows Phone 8 Applications on Windows 8

But you the Express Versions of Visual Studio are only for non-commercial purpose. If you want to create commercial applications you need a professional version.

Greets
p3root

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as Update 3 has just come out I'll go ahead and install the different versions of Express and see how it all goes. Will mark as correct if all goes well!

Comment: Well I never got around to trying the different Express versions as I purchased the Professional version which does include Blend.