# WPF Image Control, Source Property, Where does the Browser Button go in VS2013?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

In the `VS2010`, if we open `WPF`'s `Image Control`'s `Properties Explorer`, we can find its `Source` Property having `Browser Button` to add our `Image`:

[image]

In `VS2013`, I cannot find the `Browse Button` in the `Properties Explorer` - `Source` Property, although the property is still there:

[image]

Where does it go? Can we still add `Image` by browsing in `VS2013`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also find this issue compare when using VS2010. But what I have found, to add  image for drop down list source, you may follow below step:-

1. Find folder "Images" on your solutions explorer

[image]

2. Right click, select Add-->Existing Item..(shortcut **Shift + Alt + A**) and browse for your image by changing the filters to "Images Files"  or "All files".
3. After you have selected your image, it will be listing on the folder Images content.
4. Rebuild and open back the source drop down and select your desired image.

I don't know much on deep term or knowledge. But this is how I find can be use when I start using VS2015 at least.

Hope this can help you

**EDITED:**
**# Based from Visual Studio Professional 2015**

Another things that I have found, on my VS2015, it also have "Blend for Visual Studio 2015" alongside with "Visual Studio 2015" and it have what you need:-

1. Right click *.sln file and select "Open With -->"
2. Select "Blend for Visual Studio".
3. OR open "Blend for Visual Studio" program and open solution using it

[image]

For Visual Studio 2013, I believe have "Blend for Visual Studio 2013" as stated on this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171012(v=vs.120).aspx)
[image]
Link [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#d-professional).

For comment on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17361522/3436326), Express version does not comes with Blend as it for non-commercial purposes